# C++ Calling child method from parent type without knowing child type

Tags: c++

I am trying to convert a project from c# to c++ and have come across a piece of functionality I am not sure on how to implement in c++.

I have a list (or vector) of objects, all casted to their parent type. In c# I can call a function from an object in this list without knowing the child and the appropriate child function will be called, however I am not sure how to make this certain functionality work in c++.

Code snippet from C#:

```
        public void AddComponent(IComponent component)
    {
        Debug.Assert(component != null, "Component must not be null");

        componentList.Add(component);
        mask |= component.ComponentMask;
    }
```

Retrieves the ComponentMask enum value from the Component and performs bitwise operation correctly.

Code snippet from C++:

```
void oEntity::AddComponent(IComponent &componentIn)
{
    componentList.push_back(componentIn);
    mask |= componentIn.ComponentMask();
}
```

This returns the error "IComponent cannot instantiate abstract class", if I remove the brackets from the method the operator overload no longer works and throws the error "binary '|=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'overloaded-function' (or there is no acceptable conversion)"

The mask value is an enum that contains bit shifted ints used as a flag to identify the component type. Operator has also been overloaded appropriately to work with the enum type.

Comment: *I have a list (or vector) of objects, all casted to their parent type*. That's a problem in C++. Your code suffers from [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing). Use a `std::vector<shared_ptr<IComponent*>>` instead.

Comment: [Get a couple of good C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) and start reading. Of special interest for this problem, read about *pointers*, *polymophism* and *virtual functions*.

Comment: In C++, runtime polymorphism is based on pointers. You need vector/list of pointers of type `IComponent*` (or unique/shared pointers) and then store pointers to instances of inherited classes. Via these pointers, you can then call virtual methods such as `ComponentMask`.

Comment: Correction to my previous comment. Use a `std::vector<shared_ptr<IComponent>>` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your speedy responses, they were very helpful and helped me fix my problem and also made me learn something in the process.

Answer (score 0):

The OP has already figured it out, so this is for anyone else coming across this question.

In C++, you can declare `virtual` methods (you can also declare *pure* virtual methods, but that's a bit more complex). These methods can be overwritten by child classes, but *must* be implemented them selves as well, or you'll get some [cryptic errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23255256/undefined-reference-to-vtable-for-class-constructor).

If you want them to do nothing by default, the easiest solution is to just define them with an empty body. Here's a simple example:

```
class ParentClass
{
    int x, y;
    virtual void handleNewPos(int newX, int newY){}

public:
    ParentClass(int x, int y)
    {
        resetPos(x, y);
    }

    void resetPos(int newX, int newY)
    {
        handleNewPos(newX, newY);
        x = newX;
        y = newY;
    }
}

class ChildClass: public ParentClass
{
    // marked 'override' because it's replacing a previous virtual method that had the same
    // return type / params. Not required, but if you're using C++11 or greater, than it's
    // preferred 
    virtual void handleNewPos(int newX, int newY) override
    {
        // Every time the resetPos method is called, it prints out it's new position.
        std::cout << "New Position: " << newX << ", " << newY << std::endl;
    }      

public:
    ChildClass(int x, int y): ParentClass(x, y) {}                                          
}
```